# Hazelcast 3.6.1 Aggregation

Tags: hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast 3.6.1. It is set up as a server/client. A Map is on the server (single node) and it is about 4Gb of data. My program creates a client and then needs to look up some data (very small in size - like 30MB). So I was getting the data from the map and looping through all of it to search for the data of interest - before I knew it the process size was 4Gb (as I did a get on the map for each piece of data I was analyzing it was loading it into memory (Lazy) until all the data was loaded!). So, I discovered that I could use aggregation which I was under the impression was all done server side and only the part I was interested in was returned to the client, but the client process still grows to 350MB!

Is aggregation solely done on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing it appears that the collator portion of the aggregator is being done on the client.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should upgrade to Hazelcast 3.8.x versions since the new aggregation system is way faster. Apart from that it depends on what you try to aggregate, but if you do real aggregations like sum, min or similar, aggregations is the way to got. The documentation for 3.8.x fast-aggregations is available here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.3/manual/html-single/index.html#fast-aggregations

Comment: Switched to 3.8.3 and it works great and is MUCH simpler!